# Would a Phaser Overheat?

Tags: star-trek, technology, phaser

Would a phaser have problems with overheating? This issue hasn't been raised during any altercations in the show that I know of - the operator keeps firing the weapon without a worry.

General knowledge of heat based weapons would indicate that there must be some threshold where the weapon would overheat. Has this ever come up in any of the series?

Comment: Well, there's certainly instances of *overloading*, but I don't think that has anything to do with overheating.  My best guess would be there are safety mechanisms that prevent such overheating

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

That's why they have [**phaser coolant**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phaser_coolant): to stop overheat from happening. In the TOS episode [Balance of Terror](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Balance_of_Terror_(episode)), there's a leak in the phaser coolant with disastrous consequences.

Slightly less canonically, according to the novel [*Vendetta*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vendetta), every time a type-2 phaser is fired at level sixteen, there is an automatic six-second cool-down period, otherwise the phaser will overheat and possibly explode.

Comment: Mate, you seriously have to start watching Trek! +1

Comment: @TheDoc Maybe I'll wait to get a [star-trek] tag badge or two and *then* start watching it? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor : +1 When the new Trek series comes around on television, I'll petition the writers to name a star system "Rand-al'Thor".  The inhabits of Rand-al'Thor have never met the Federation or Starfleet, yet know massive amounts of information about them.... ;-)

Comment: Does this also apply to hand phasers? What about phaser rifles?

Comment: @forest The *Vendetta* info is about hand phasers, apparently; I've edited to clarify.